# Does fixing the Checkstyle INFOs improve performance of the Java code

Tags: java, performance, checkstyle

I was wondering while fixing the CheckStyle infos if that leads to any performance improvement. I understand that info cannot be taken seriously but still any comment will be appreciated.

I personally do not think they offer any such improvement but I can be wrong hence better to seek expert advice :)

Comment: "CheckStyle infos"? What is that, exactly? Is that a subset of CheckStyle's checks dedicated to performance?

Comment: did you mean `CheckStyle Plugin` suggestions ?

Comment: Yes @sansix, I meant apart from errors, warnings Checkstyle plugin shows INFO.

Comment: Note that what Checkstyle shows as INFO severity depends entirely on the Checkstyle configuration. Any rule can be configured to have INFO severity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you refer to the standard Checkstyle checks: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html They refer to the *style* of the source code, not really to the "style of programming". For example, code formatting ("ArrayTrailingComma", "GenericWhitespace"...) will NOT affect the actual *bytecode* that is generated from that class. There may be a class that causes hundreds of warnings, and anothe class that is free of warnings, and in the end, they may compile to identical bytecode.

SOME of the checks may however influence the code in a way that changes the bytecode, and thus, influences performance at least *theoretically*. For example, the "EqualsHashCode" check: If this causes you to insert an equals/hashCode method, this may of course affect the performance (but more importantly: The behavior of you program!). Something like "BooleanExpressionComplexity" might cause you to split up a complex expression, causing some more instructions to be generated in the bytecode. But in general, these changes should not have a really *noticable* effect on performance.

Comment: I would expect many of the suggestions actually resulting in slightly *weaker* peformance, but higher-quality code. CheckStyle simply isn't about performance at all.

Comment: As you also said, most of them are not intended to (and do not) affect the performance at all. Some (very few) might theoretically affect the performance, but this might also depend on *how* they are actually fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually one check which can boost you performance by a large factor. If you're crazy enough to write very long methods, the JIT simply gives up and you end up with a non-optimized code. I've seen a speedup factor of 8 after fixing [MethodLength](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength) (it wasn't checkstyle, it was me who said that the method was too long).

Comment: Sounds interesting @maaartinus. I will try. I am afraid we sometime write long methods :/

Comment: @Saik0: The one I wrote about was a CPU simulation, you know a switch with some 256 cases, each with maybe 10 lines of code, i.e., exceptionally long. But you know, shorter method are nearly always better and JIT is very good in inlining, so there's nothing to lose.